# How to enable Win-key command followed by ctrl+shift+enter for Administrator privilege elevation on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, administrator, privileges, runas

On Feb 9, 2022 out of the blue the shortcut to elevate Administrative privilege by typing a command from ***Win-key*** followed by **ctrl+shift+enter** stopped working on all my laptops and desktops running Windows 10. Since it happened simultaneously on all computers I discard the idea of a specific configuration change or software install. This behavior change must have come from Microsoft. Does anyone know how to get the functionality back?

Another strange thing I observed is that **ctrl+shift+enter** does elevate privilege for ***cmd.exe***, but only from **Win-R** launch window, not from Windows start menu search.

*Update as of On Feb 18, 2022*: Out of the blue the key combination started working again in the middle of the day on all Widows 10 installations. I checked if any updates were applied by Microsoft - none whatsoever! I would like to keep this problem open to get to the bottom of this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by windows-logo? To launch something as administrator, its ctrl+shift+enter. If you mean, opening start by pressing the winkey, followed by tying the name of a program and then ctrl-shift-enter, that still works on my end.

Comment: I had no idea this existed! Anyway, still works for me as well. I now have notepad with administrator privileges running :x

Comment: Lucky you! None of my Windows 10 installations have this feature now.

Comment: btw, do with 'windows-logo' I assume you mean the windows key + R?

Comment: No, Win-key for Cortana search (also can be activated by clicking Windows Start icon). By the way, Win-R does not work either except for cmd.exe

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running? What keyboard layouts do you have installed?